# Create a script to run a program that uses multiple input files with the same base name with the exception of one input file

Tags: shell-script, bioinformatics

I am new to scripting so I am in need of help.

I'm running a program that is based on four separate test (--max-maf)  that requires input files names and a file name for the output. Below is just a general description of the program. Filenames are inputs which I describe in detail in the next block code.

```
epacts group --groupf filename.grp --vcf filename.vcf.gz --ped filename.ped --max-maf 0.05 --kin filename --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/filename-CMC-0.05
epacts group --groupf filename.grp --vcf filename.vcf.gz --ped filename.ped --max-maf 0.03 --kin filename --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/filename-CMC-0.03
epacts group --groupf filename.grp --vcf filename.vcf.gz --ped filename.ped --max-maf 0.02 --kin filename --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/filename-CMC-0.02
epacts group --groupf filename.grp --vcf filename.vcf.gz --ped filename.ped --max-maf 0.01 --kin filename --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/filename-CMC-0.01
```

I have several input files in the same directory with the same base name with the exception of one file (CDES_MyopV1.ped) that has the same base name, but a unique identifier proceeding it . This file  will go after the --ped command (--ped CDES_MyopV1.ped)

```
CDES-genes.grp 
CDES.vcf.gz 
CDES_MyopV1.ped 
CDES.kinf
```

I tried to create a script that executes the program by finding the
input files listed above based on the base name "CDES" but, I realized that I need the .ped file to include the base name and the unique identifier after it (CDES_MyopV1) Also, for every output file, I would like to have CDES_MyopV1 concatenated to the output file name.

This is what I've attempted thus far:

```
declare -a files=("CDES")

for element in ${files[@]}
do
   epacts group --groupf $element-genes.grp --vcf $element.vcf.gz --ped $element.ped --max-maf 0.05 --kin $element.kinf  --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/$element-CMC-0.05
   epacts group --groupf $element-genes.grp --vcf $element.vcf.gz --ped $element.ped --max-maf 0.03 --kin $element.kinf  --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/$element-CMC-0.01 
   epacts group --groupf $element-genes.grp --vcf $element.vcf.gz --ped $element.ped --max-maf 0.02 --kin $element.kinf --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/$element-CMC-0.05 
   epacts group --groupf $element-genes.grp --vcf $element.vcf.gz --ped $element.ped --max-maf 0.01 --kin $element.kinf --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/$element-CMC-0.01
done
```

Ideally, this what I would like the script to do.

```
epacts group --groupf CDES-genes.grp --vcf CDES.vcf.gz --ped CDES_MyopV1.ped --max-maf 0.05 --kin CDES.kinf  --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/CDES_MyopV1-CMC-0.05
       epacts group --groupf CDES-genes.grp --vcf CDES.vcf.gz --ped CDES_MyopV1.ped --max-maf 0.03 --kin CDES.kinf  --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/CDES_MyopV1-CMC-0.03 
       epacts group --groupf CDES-genes.grp --vcf CDES.vcf.gz --ped CDES_MyopV1.ped --max-maf 0.02 --kin CDES.kinf --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/CDES_MyopV1-CMC-0.02 
       epacts group --groupf CDES-genes.grp --vcf CDES.vcf.gz --ped CDES_MyopV1.ped --max-maf 0.01 --kin CDES.kinf --test emmaxCMC --out BcA/CDES_MyopV1-CMC-0.01
```

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt. I appreciate the feedback. I have edited sections to clarify the points that you brought up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you start from the full name of the `.ped` file and then extract the needed parts via the shell parameter expansion mechanism, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a files=("CDES_MyopV1.ped")
declare -a mafs=("0.05" "0.03" "0.02" "0.01")

for file in ${files[@]}
do
   uniquename=$(basename "${file}")
   element="${uniquename%%_*}"
   for maf in ${mafs[@]}
   do
      epacts group --groupf "${element}-genes.grp" --vcf "${element}.vcf.gz" --ped "${file}" --max-maf "$maf" --kin "${element}.kinf" --test emmaxCMC --out "BcA/${uniquename}-CMC-${maf}"
   done
done
```

The variable `uniquename` will be the combination of basename "CDES" and unique suffix "_MyopV1", while the variable `element` will be the basename alone.

If you do it this way, you can easily replace the hardcoded array `files` with either a list of the actual `.ped` files in the directory, like this:

```
for file in *.ped
do
   ...
done
```

or with a list of files you pass to the script as arguments, like this:

```
for file in "${@}"
do
   ...
done
```

which you can then in turn supply to your script via wildcard expansion.

Note that I have systematically enclosed variable names in braces which is recommended to avoid possible syntactical ambiguities.
I have also enclosed all filenames in double quotes to avoid problems in case a filename contains whitespace characters.